# How to pass global credential parameters to jenkins from bash script

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, gitlab

How to run the batch script from the server to trigger a job in Jenkins which uses global credentials (secret file) like a password for a database server?

I have created one parametrized job in Jenkins which executes the bash command placed on server to take a database backup, for which this batch job uses a database password from Jenkins's global credentials. This job is successful when I execute from the Jenkins console.

Now, I want to execute this job using bash script by passing parameter (using a crumb token), bash wants to utilize the credentials placed in the Jenkins global credential set. Can this batch script utilize the global credentials from Jenkins (in this case, the database password?)

```
#!/bin/bash

##this generates the crumb token
crumb=$(curl -u "userid:pswd" -s 'http://<jenkins-url>:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')

##this will call the remote job where i am passing the variables
curl -u "userid:pswd" -H "$crumb" -X POST  http://<jenkins-url>:8080/job/backup-to-aws/buildWithParameters?MYSQL_HOST=db_host&DATABASE_NAME=testdb&AWS_BUCKET_NAME=<bkt-name>&DB_PASSWD=<how should i pass this secret credential stored in jenkins>
```

I want to run the batch script from the server which uses the Jenkins stored global credentials like the db password. How to make use of these credentials while passing along with the script from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl -u "userID:pswd" -H "$crumb" -X POST http://<jenkins-url>:8080/job/Daily-Backup-Job/buildWithParameters?J_DB_NAME=mysql&J_DB_SERVER=db_host&J_BUCKET_NAME=<name-of-my-bucket>&J_DB_PASSWD=${DB_PASSWD}&J_AWS_PASS=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_PASSWORD}
```

this statement has worked successfully where ${DB_PASSWD} and ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_PASSWORD} are actually a parameters defined in jenkins global credentials variable i.e. DB_PASSWD and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_PASSWORD are the ID for those credentials respectively

Comment: Did you answer your own question or adding more information ? Clarify, and either edit your question w/these details or mark this as answered. But you should provide more context if it's an answer.

Comment: This is the answer to my previous question, i found it from other forums or studies, posted it with a solution here. While submitting, I have already posted this as an answer

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure. For me it is showing as '1 answer'

Comment: Yes, it shows '1 answer', but I am suggesting you ["accept" the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check-mark, thereby turning it green.

Comment: Ok thank you for sharing this, I have done as suggested :)